# Project directory structure so I can import package for unittest

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest

I am confused how to structure a project containing a package and a unittest.

I have this directory structure:

```
TestProject/
├── package
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── package.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_package.py
└── usage.py
```

**constants.py**

```
A = 1
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .package import give_A
```

**package.py**

```
from .constants import *

def give_A():
    return A
```

**usage.py**

```
from package import give_A

print(give_A())
```

**test_package.py**

```
import unittest
from package import give_A

class Test_package(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertEqual(give_A(), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Everything works until I try to run the `test_package.py` module, which understandably cannot import package:

```
~/Python/TestProject/package/tests $ python3 test_package.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_package.py", line 3, in <module>
    from package import give_A
ImportError: No module named 'package'
```

However, this seems to be preferred structure of package / tests. How can I make it work? Or should I do it completely differently (structure, directories, imports, test execution...)?

Comment: try `from package.package import give_A`?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named package.package`. There is no reason why it should work, as package is not in PYTHONPATH, right?

Comment: Where are you trying to run the script from?

Comment: Try running it from the package directory `python3 tests/test_package.py`

Comment: `from .constants import * ...
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Setup your `PYTHONPATH` such that `TestProject` is in it.
2. Run tests using unittest like this:

   `~/Python/TestProject $ python3 -m package.tests.test_package`
3. Use unittest commendline interface:

   `~/Python/TestProject $ python3 -m unittest package/tests/test_package.py`

For more information see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface

Comment: I get `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` if I try relative import. Adding to `PYTHONPATH` works, but is that common practice?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3 either  you set PYTHONPATH or you need to run with python -m package.tests.test_package.

Comment: That works. Do people expect to run tests like that? Or do people include shell script to run tests?

Comment: The documentation suggest to run tests with the unittest command line interface: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface. Not sure if that's applicable and works with your example without further tweaks.

Comment: Cool! I have missed that.